# Usage of conjunction 'and'

Tags: grammar

> Where it becomes murkier is when using behavioural science and data
> strays into manipulation.

In this sentence, a form of two verbs on both sides of 'and' in when claused are different.

A former is a -ing form(straying) and a latter is a Present tense verb (strays).

Could someone tell me how could it be possible grammatically, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, the phrase "using behavioural science and data" is what strays.  The word "using" here is a *gerund*: a form derived from a verb, but functions as a noun.